# Retrieving list of people who use the same requesting application using Google Sigin SDK

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

When a user sign-in using Google sign-in SDK is there any way to retrieve the users friends list who are already authenticated / sing-in to my app ? I did not find anything related to this in new Google People API. The old Google+ API has this. am I missing something ?

Thanks